# Connecting to Domain from different subnet

Tags: active-directory, domain, subnet

I am trying to connect to a domain controller that is on a different subnet..

The active directory domain controller/dns server (same box) is on the 192.168.0.0 subnet. Any computer on this same subnet can connect perfectly fine to the domain.

When I try to connect a computer that is on a different subnet, 192.168.2.0, it fails..

I get this error message when attempting to connect:

```
 DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to
 locate a domain controller for domain "cblad.cbl-uh.com":

 The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.dc.domain.com
```

All the computers DNS settings are pointing to the DNS server and NetBIOS over TCP/IP is also enabled on all the computers involved.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a firewall between the subnets? If so, you'll invariably need to allow domain related communication through the firewall.

Comment: draw us a diagram of how things are physically connected, it will probably help out a whole lot. nothing fancy, MS paint will do.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is kind of all over the place and you're clearly missing some fundamentals.

255.255.0.0 and 255.255.255.0 are not subnets, they are subnet masks and are used to calculate what bits of your IP address identifies the NETWORK and what bits identify the HOST.

Example:

IP:192.168.0.1
MASK: 255.255.255.0

In this case the NETWORK(SUBNET) is 192.168.0.0, with usable addresses between 192.168.0.1 through 192.168.0.254. What this means is that a router is not required for these devices to communicate on the same physical network. If however your machine is on a different network entirely let's say 192.168.2.X then a router is required to route packets between these two networks.

So, to get to the point here, you should use the same subnet mask for all your devices, unless you're intending to segment them into seperate networks, and even then the subnet MASK will probably be the same, it's the IP addresses that will change.

Comment: Yup, I'd start with the basics: can you ping the DC or any address on that other subnet?

Comment: I updated the post.. The domain is on a 0.0 network and the workstation i want to connect is on a 2.0 network

and I can ping the DC from that workstation

Comment: Then it sounds like Layer 3 is ok. You should ask yourself why the DNS query is failing, not what's wrong with the "network"

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you query the DNS server from one of the problem systems? For an AD "foo" in "bar.com", I should be able to run the following nslookup on a Linux box (or use a Windows box, same principle):

```
$ nslookup
> set type=any
> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.foo.bar.com
Server:         A.B.C.D
Address:        A.B.C.D#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.foo.bar.com     service = 0 100 389 dc1.foo.bar.com.
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.foo.bar.com     service = 0 100 389 dc2.foo.bar.com.
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.foo.bar.com     service = 0 100 389 dc3.foo.bar.com.
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.foo.bar.com     service = 0 100 389 dc4.foo.bar.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
_msdcs.foo.bar.com   nameserver = dc1.foo.bar.com.
dc3.foo.bar.com      internet address = A.B.E.F
dc4.foo.bar.com      internet address = A.B.E.G
dc1.foo.bar.com      internet address = A.B.E.H
dc2.foo.bar.com      internet address = A.B.E.I
```

with suitable substitutions for IP addresses and hostnames. I'm guessing you don't get similar results, indicating a problem in the DNS server you're pointing to.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. With above your mentioned instructions, I am getting authoritative answers with internet address as well. What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this may help or not but if your DNS is configured correctly and you can ping the DC then you have a route to the DC.  The next question is do you have an ACL (Access List) on you router you probably do.  I would check to see if you have enabled both TCP and UDP for the DNS server on the router access list just a thought.  Hope it helps.

Dean

Answer (score -1):

In my case was the problem the the client trying to login still was using SMB1, while the rest of the domain enforced SMB2.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858

Comment: This has nothing to do with subnets; if this was the problem, client connectivity would everything in the network, not on a specific subnet.

Comment: Also, this is a question from 2011...